# How to display the n x 2 values of the date in mongodb using aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation, nosql-aggregation

I want to take 2n values from the database. In the below example I need to 2 points increment value in the mongodb database collection

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "abc", "price" : 10, "quantity" : 2, "date" : ISODate("2014-03-01T08:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "jkl", "price" : 20, "quantity" : 1, "date" : ISODate("2014-03-01T09:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : "xyz", "price" : 5, "quantity" : 10, "date" : ISODate("2014-03-15T09:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 4, "item" : "xyz", "price" : 5, "quantity" : 20, "date" : ISODate("2014-04-04T11:21:39.736Z") }
{ "_id" : 5, "item" : "abc", "price" : 10, "quantity" : 10, "date" : ISODate("2014-04-04T21:23:13.331Z") }
```

The output i am expecting is like this

```
 { "_id" : 2, "item" : "jkl", "price" : 20, "quantity" : 1, "date" : ISODate("2014-03-01T09:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 4, "item" : "xyz", "price" : 5, "quantity" : 20, "date" : ISODate("2014-04-04T11:21:39.736Z") }
..............
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: It's very hard to understand the exact behaviour you're expecting. From the title it seems you'd like to filter on even dates, but I can't find a pattern between your input and your output linked to the date. Are you just looking at even _id values?

Comment: Yes even id values or values which we prefer. You are right @xaiver Guihot

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`$mod`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/mod/) (modulo) operator with a `find` query:

```
db.collection.find({ _id: { $mod: [2, 0]} })
```

Or *(as mentioned in the title of your question)* with an `aggregate` query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{ $match: { _id: { $mod: [2, 0] } } }])
```